# Changing instruments in midi encoding?

Tags: java, android, midi

I'm trying to write a function to dynamically create midi files on Android. Since there is no javax.sound.midi library I'm just writing the bytes out to file myself. I've found some great guides (see below) so I've been able to create multiple track midis. However I haven't been able to figure out how to switch instruments for any of the tracks so everythign is just using the default instrument. 
I think from the documents I read the code I need is to "program change" followed by the program number.

What I've tried so far is writing the following out to a byteoutputstream array:

```
track.write((byte) 192); // 128 + 64
track.write((byte) x); // x is the instrument number between 1-128.
```

I've put this before the start of the note on/ note off track information, but it doesn't seem to do anything except make the midi take a long time to start. Am I on the right track here, or am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.

http://faydoc.tripod.com/formats/mid.htm
https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~craig/articles/linuxmidi/misc/essenmidi.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. It was a just a simple thing, but I forgot to include track time before the program change. Once I added the 0 byte it worked.